# Strange edges in the input fields and heights with non-integer value

Tags: css, less

I was writing some CSS for a very common user login form, except that when I logged in from another computer with the same browser (Firefox) and operating system (Ubuntu), some strange white borders emerged on the outside.

What's even stranger is that they tend to appear and disappear simply by resizing the window.

Because? how can this be prevented?

Thanks everyone for the help! :)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="npt nptFocus">
    <span>Aa</span>
    <input type="text" name="usr" placeholder="Nickname">
</div>
```

**LESS:**

```
// Palette
@main_color: blue;

@main: darken(saturate(@main_color, -97%), 25%);
@neutral: saturate(darken(@main_color, -25%), -25%);
@verde: #118769;
@rosso: #fe5f55;
@bianco: darken(saturate(@main_color, -40%), -45%);

@v_soft = 10%;
@v_medium = 25%;
@v_hard = 40%;

@neutral_dark: darken(@neutral, @v_soft);
@verde_dark: darken(@verde, @v_soft);
@rosso_dark: darken(@rosso, @v_hard);

@main_light: lighten(@main, @v_hard);
@main_dark: darken(@main, 8%);

@radius: 5px;

.npt {
    display: table;
    background: @bianco;
    border-radius: @radius;
    border: solid 1px @main_light;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;

    input, span{
        display: table-cell;
        padding: 10px;
        transition: 0.25s;
    }

    input {
        border: none;
        background: none;
        border-radius: 0px;
        color: @main;
        width: 100%;
    }

    span {
        border-right: solid 1px darken(@main_light, -15%);
        color: darken(@main, -40%);
        background: darken(@main_light, -25%);
        padding-left: 15px;
        padding-right: 15px;
        width: 55px;
    }

    &.nptFocus {
        border: solid 1px @neutral_dark;
        span {
            border-right: solid 1px @neutral_dark;
            color: @bianco;
            background: @neutral_dark;
        }
    }
}
```

**SCREEN:**
[image]

**UPDATE 1: Added compiled CSS**

```
.npt {
  display: table;
  background: #ebebfa;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: solid 1px #a3a3a8;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.npt input,
.npt span {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: 0.25s;
}
.npt input {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  border-radius: 0px;
  color: #3e3e42;
  width: 100%;
}
.npt span {
  border-right: solid 1px #cacace;
  color: #a3a3a8;
  background: #e5e5e6;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  width: 55px;
}
.npt.nptFocus {
  border: solid 1px #6363e9;
}
.npt.nptFocus span {
  border-right: solid 1px #6363e9;
  color: #ebebfa;
  background: #6363e9;
}
.npt.nptError {
  border: solid 1px #fe5f55;
}
.npt.nptError span {
  border-right: solid 1px #fe5f55;
  color: #ebebfa;
  background: #fe5f55;
}
.npt.nptError.nptFocus {
  border: solid 1px #d38580;
}
.npt.nptError.nptFocus span {
  border-right: solid 1px #d38580;
  background: #d38580;
}
.npt.nptOk {
  border: solid 1px #118769;
}
.npt.nptOk span {
  border-right: solid 1px #118769;
  color: #ebebfa;
  background: #118769;
}
.npt.nptOk.nptFocus {
  border: solid 1px #6cac9b;
}
.npt.nptOk.nptFocus span {
  border-right: solid 1px #6cac9b;
  background: #6cac9b;
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**
[image]

Following the help of @Manas Khandelwal and the tests carried out together, it seems that this is due to a browser rendering error as the logo above the form, having the width declared as a percentage, will never have a height with an integer value .

Ideas?

Really the only solution is really having to round all the heights via JavaScript?

```
$('.roundHeight').each(function(){
    if(!$(this).is("[data-exmargin]")) $(this).attr('data-exmargin',parseFloat($(this).css('marginTop')));
    var d = parseFloat($(this).attr('data-exmargin')) - ($(this).height() - Math.floor($(this).height()));
    $(this).css('marginTop', d + 'px');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `outline: none;` to the input element;

> Codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/WNGgQwP

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't seem to have any effect .. :(

Comment: @Pinguto Can you share your compiled css.

Comment: @ Manas Khandelwal CSS Added..:)

Comment: @Pinguto let me see

Comment: See this: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/LYRJpQz let me know if you see I because it seems ok to me as I am not able to see any of it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227112/discussion-between-pinguto-and-manas-khandelwal).